# Удаление символических имен препроцессором

Tags: c++, препроцессор

В каких условиях препроцессор может удалить символическое имя `SOME_VAL`:

```
#define SOME_VAL 1.43
```

Так сказано в книге *"Эффективное использование С++. 55 верных советов улучшить структуру и код ваших программ"* Скотта Мейерса, во втором правиле.

---

Выдеркжка из книги:

> ```
> #define ASPECT_RAIO 1.653
> ```
>
> "Символическое имя ASPECT_RATIO может так и остаться неизвестным
>   компилятору или быть удалено препроцессором до того, как код поступит
>   на обработку компилятору..."

Comment: А можно контекст (текст совета)?

Comment: Скорее всего в данном случае имеется ввиду, что строчка `#define ASPECT_RAIO 1.653` лучше чем `const float ASPECT_RAIO = 1.653;` потому что, если имя ASPECT_RAIO не задействовано в программе, то оно не будет подшито в код (препроцессор его не передаст компилятору), а если обьявлено явно константой - то оно всегда попадёт в компилятор (компилятор будет анализировать, оставить имя или удалить, для чего будет считать и анализировать xrefs на это имя).

Comment: Препроцессорные имена не будут видны компилятору в *любых* условиях. То есть с точки зрения собственно компилятора, таки имена удалены всегда.

Comment: тут нужно понимать то, что когда то давно препроцессор был отдельным процессом. И компилятор действительно не знал о том, что есть define. На данный момент компиляторы "содержат" препроцессор внутри и сами делают препроцессирование. Поэтому, де-юре  они не знают, а де-факто - знают. Но это не мешает им не показывать ошибки, возникшие в результате препроцессирования.

Comment: @AnT интересует не с точки зрения компилятора, а со стороны препроцессора: в каких условиях оно (имя) может быть удалено препроцессором?

Comment: @khirnick: Удалено откуда именно? Препроцессорные имена никогда не осталяют никакого следа в коде. То есть они удалаются *всегда*, в любых условиях. После завершения работы препроцессора от них не остается никакого следа.

Comment: @khirnick повторюсь, чуть иначе скажу, на счёт удаления. Предпроцессор создаёт "расшифрованый" код для компилятора. Поэтому для него "удалено" - понятие достаточно символично. Вам правильно говорят что препроцессорные имена никогда не осталяют никакого следа. А вот для компилятора удаление неиспользующихся констант/переменных "компилятора" - процедура достаточно трудоёмкая, я думаю что  автор вашей книги хотел донести это преимущество предпроцессорных констант, над "констант-компилятора".

Comment: @nick_n_a не помню точно, но где-то кто-то говорил мне, что связь между препроцессорными именами и значениями где-то остается или, возможно, это ошибочно?

Comment: Связь остаётся, если препроцессорное имя задействовано (и то как результат разшифровки предпроцессора, указано будет именно связь с строкой где кодово произошло использование, а код там будет такой как расшифровал предпроцессор). Если же нет - то оно не подшивается и в дальнейшем не анализируется.

Comment: @nick_n_a теперь разобрался. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Препроцессор может его удалить, обойдя через #if #else #endif или удалив его явно через #undef. Все операции  препроцессора осуществляются до компиляции и ASPECT_RAIO не является символом в прямом смысле этого слова, везде в коде оно будет заменено продекларированным значением, если #define остался известен.

Отсюда известная хохма:

```
#define true false // Счастливой вам отладки!
```

Макроопределения - очень мощный инструмент для создания переносимого кода, или для метапрограммирования. Вот , например:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN 
    #define WRITENGINE qDebug
    #define WRITE(x)            do {if (debugConsole) qDebug x; } while(0)
#else
    #define WRITENGINE printf
#endif

#define C2_DBG_FMT "DD %s:%d:%s(): "

#ifdef DEBUG

    static volatile bool local_debug_flag = DEFAULT_SHOW_DEBUG;    

    #define SHOW_DEBUG(f)          do { local_debug_flag = f; }  while(0)

    #define shortdebug(fmt, ...)   do{if(local_debug_flag) WRITENGINE (fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);} while(0)

#ifdef SHORT_DEBUG
    #define debug(fmt, ...)        shortdebug(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
    #define debug(fmt,...)              do{if(local_debug_flag) WRITENGINE (C2_DBG_FMT fmt,__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__);} while(0)     
#endif
```

Comment: счастливой отладки это такое `#define true (rand() % 2)`

Comment: @KoVadim а да, помню, такое тоже было. Причем реально примененное обиженным программистом перед уходом

Answer (score 0):

Согласно деталям, которые можно найти в Интернете, речь в этом совете (совет номер 2) идет именно о том, что имя `ASPECT_RATIO` будет (может быть) удалено препроцессором. И если с этим значением возникнут какие-то проблемы на стадии компиляции или на стадии отладки, то его уже нельзя будет связать с именем `ASPECT_RATIO` (кроме как ручным поиском).

Почему в книге говорится, что имя только "может быть" удалено - не ясно. В традиционной реализации оно *будет* удалено (заменено на `1.43`) на стадии препроцессинга, и на стадии компиляции от него уже не останется и следа. Возможно, что предполагается теоретическое существование какой-то особо умной реализации, которая умеет сохранять соотвествие между подставленными в код литералами и их оригинальными макро-именами. Мне такие реализации не известны.

Comment: Неизвестны? Да ладно? http://ideone.com/ylXekT: _"prog.cpp:5:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘SMTH’"_ или ты что-то другое имел в виду?

Comment: собственно об этом я выше и пишу. де-факто, компилятор давно делает препроцессирование сам. И прекрасно знает о простых случаях.

Comment: `gcc -g3` делает макросы доступными в `gdb`. В этом случае `gcc -g3 -E` препроцессор оставляет `#define` в файле, который поступает на вход компилятору (а тот оставляет "ссылки" на их текст в объектном файле)

Comment: @avp  значение того, что стоит  после -g может варьироваться от версии и платформы,  задание формата цифрами плохо документировано, обычно  пишут -gcoff+ и т.д. 3 это какой формат - stabs, COFF , XCOFF , или DWARF 2?

Comment: @Swift, не знаю, какой формат, исследуйте если интересно.

Comment: @avp К сожалению, нет ничего под рукой, платформы на работе поддерживают  только COFF и XCOFF (gcc 4.7 max), древний gdb, не поддерживающий DWARF2. однако может появится рычаг для давления на разрабов, с метапрограммированием проблем много.